# If $a > b$, is $a^2 > b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $a > b$, where $a,b ∈ ℝ$, is it always true that $a^2 > b^2$?

Comment: Look at the graph of $y=x^2$, and notice that when $x$ is negative, $y$ decreases when $x$ increases, but when $x$ is positive, $y$ increases when $x$ increases. http://www.wsd1.org/waec/math/pre-calculus%20advanced/quadratic%20functions/Terminology/termintro.htm

Comment: Related: [Showing $a^2<b^2$, if $0<a<b$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52877/showing-a2-b2-if-0-a-b)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

no its not. When $a,b$ are positive it happens. Consider $a=-2$ and $b =-3$. notice that inequality reverses.

Answer (score 145):

If $\: \color{#c00}{a > b}\: $ then $\: a^2\! -\! b^2 = (\color{#c00}{a\!-\!b})(a\!+\!b) > 0 \iff a\!+\!b >0 $

Comment: Now that is neat!

Comment: -which can also be taken as an allusion to a certain scenario involving the First Law of Thermodynamics, in which the change in energy of the system is positive, and a and b are associated with the work and heat, not necessarily respectively, of the process.

Comment: Bill, this has left quite an impression on me, apparently! See [this recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/122931/7850)

Comment: @TheChaz I'm not sure on whose shoulders we stand here, but, alas, if only they were broader, so that there might have been room for the OP to enjoy the view too! Thanks for the shoulder company.

Comment: I don't get it, this is obviously wrong for 0 > (-a) > b

Comment: @Julian Equivalently it states $\rm\ (a-b)(a+b) \le 0 \iff a+b \le 0\ $ when $\,a>b,\,$ which *is true* when  $\ b < -a < 0\,\ (\iff a+b < 0 < a)$

Answer (score 19):

The correct statement is,$$|a|>|b|\iff a^2 > b^2 $$A counterexample of your hypothesis is $a = 7, b = -8.$

Yes, $a >b $, but $b^2 > a^2$, i.e.:$$ (-8)^2 > 7^2\\64 > 49$$

Comment: One definition of |a| is $|a|=\sqrt{a^2}$. As the square root is monotonic this statement is natural.

Answer (score 10):

If $a > b > 0$ then $a^2 > b^2$.

$a > b$ means there is a positive $k$ such that $a = b + k$. Squaring this equation we have $a^2 = b^2 + (2bk + k^2)$ but $2bk + k^2$ is just another positive so $a^2 > b^2$.

The reason we know $2bk + k^2$ is positive is because of the ordered field axioms, one says if $x$ and $y$ are positive so is $xy$ and another says that $x+y$ is positive. That is why we need $b$ to be positive.

Answer (score 7):

The conclusion is correct on $[0, +\infty)$ because that is precisely the interval over which the function $f(x) = x^2$ is an increasing function. No algebra is necessary. Draw the parabola and LOOK!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. In this case, we can write:

$a>b \implies a-b>0 \implies (a+b)(a-b)>0 \implies (a^2)-(b^2)>0$

Comment: This leaves the false impression, for the layman, that it is a necessary condition that a and b be positive for the inequality to occur, but I will refrain from down-voting your answer. The perfect answer, above, was given by Bill Dubuque.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $ a > b $, it is not always true that $ a^{2} > b^{2} $. One counterexample would be that one of $ a $ or $ b $ is negative, say $ a = 1 $, and $ b = -1 $. Then $$ a^2 = 1^{2} = 1 $$ and $$ b^{2} = (-1)^{2} = 1 $$ making $ a^2 = b^2 $, a contradiction of our assumption that $ a^{2} > b^{2} $.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the same as Bill Dubuque's, but goes into a bit more detail. The question

> Does $a>b$ imply that $a^2>b^2$?

is equivalent to

> Does $a-b>0$ imply that $a^2-b^2>0$?

In other words, the answer to the bottom question is the same as the answer to the top question.

By factorising $a^2-b^2$, we see that no, $a-b>0$ *does not* imply that $a^2-b^2>0$:
$$
a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b) > 0 \text{ if, and only if, $a+b>0$} \, .
$$
We know that $a-b>0$, but that is not enough. We also require that $a+b>0$ so that $(a+b)(a-b)>0$. If we instead ask

> Does $a>b$ and $a>-b$ imply that $a^2>b^2?$

then the answer is in the affirmative.