# Showing $a^2 < b^2$, if $0 < a < b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

Lately, I've been stumbling with proofs of inequalities.

For example:

> Given $0 < a < b$
>   Show $a^2 < b^2$

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far:

> $a^2 < b^2$
>   $\sqrt{a^2} < \sqrt{b^2}$
>   $a < b$

```
OR
```

> $a < b$
>   $a^2 < b^2$

However, neither of these solutions seem to be really "showing" that $a^2 < b^2$, assuming $0 < a < b$. I've tried some other things, but to no avail. Am I merely overthinking the problem when, in fact, these are actually acceptable solutions, or am I truly missing something here?

Comment: Yes, your first "proof" (it's actually backwards) uses the property that $a^2 < b^2 \implies \sqrt{a^2} < \sqrt{b^2}$, and the second one uses the property that $a<b \implies a^2 < b^2$, which is what you're asked to prove — so you can't use it. (A warning sign should be that nowhere you used $0 < a$.) Instead, you could, for instance, show that if $b-a>0$ (and $a>0$), then $b^2 - a^2 > 0$, *without* using a property like the ones you used above. (It's easy!)

Comment: @Theo: It's even simpler to say that $b^2 - a^2 = (b-a)(b+a) > 0$ because both factors in the product are positive. :-) (The first factor because $b-a > 0$, and the second because both $a$ and $b$ are positive.)

Comment: @ShrevatsaR: Agreed, much better :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have

\begin{align*}
(a-b) &< 0  \\ \Longrightarrow (a-b) \cdot (a+b) &<0  \qquad\qquad \Bigl[\small\text{Multiplying both sides by}\ (a+b) \ \text{doesn't change the sign.} \Bigr]\\ \Longrightarrow a^{2}-b^{2} &< 0
\end{align*}

Or consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ given by $f(x) =x^{2}$. Clearly this monotonic because $f'(x) = 2x > 0$ for all $x >0$. Hence your claim follows.

Comment: Wonderful! I had thought I might need to show a progression from `a < b` to `a^2 < b^2`, but I had been going about it in the wrong way. Thank you for making it so simple and easy to understand.

Comment: To be more precise, "monotonically increasing", since the result would not follow if it was monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 12):

Recall that multiplication by a positive number preserves order: since $a > 0$, then from $a < b$ you get $aa < ab$, and since $b > 0$, then from $a < b$ you get $ab < bb$. Together, this gives $aa < ab < bb$, hence $a^2 < b^2$.

Comment: This is actually one of the methods that I tried. For whatever reason, however, I did not make the connection between `aa < ab` and `ab < bb`. Thank you for letting me know I was on the right path. Hopefully next time I will be more observative.

Comment: Glad you found this answer useful.

Answer (score 9):

$$0<a<b\Rightarrow 0\cdot a<a\cdot a<b\cdot a<b\cdot b\Rightarrow
a^{2}<b^{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

If $0<a<b$ then both $b-a>0$, $b+a>0$.
This implies that

$$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)>0,$$

which is equivalent to $b^2>a^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Specialize  $\rm\ A,B = a,b\ $ in the $ $ **Inequality Product Rule** $ $ below.

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ \color{#0a0}{b>a,\:B>A}\ \Rightarrow\ b\:B>a\:A\ $ **if** $ $ *at most one* of $\rm\ a,b,A,B\:$ is $\:\le 0$

**Proof** $\rm\quad bB\!-\!aA = \color{#c00}b\,(\color{#0a0}{B\!-\!A})+(\color{#0a0}{b\!-\!a})\color{#c00}A > 0\ $ by wlog $\rm\ a \le 0\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{b,A} > 0\:$

**Note** $\ $ The proof is essentially the same as the well-known proof of the [Congruence Product Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/very-simple-question-but-what-is-the-proof-that-x-y-mod-m-x-mod-m-y-mod-m/5376#5376) a rule which lies at the heart of many product rules (e.g. for derivatives - see said post).