# Square Root Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can I prove the following inequality:

> > Given $ a,b>0 $ and $a^2>b $, we have $a>\sqrt b$

Thank you.

Comment: Note: the answer is *highly* dependent on how much you already know about inequalities.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$a^2 > b \Leftrightarrow (a - \sqrt{b})(a + \sqrt{b}) > 0$

Both of these factors must be positive, since both $a$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are positive. In particular, $a - \sqrt{b} > 0$

---

Indeed, I stand [on the shoulders of giants](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8362/7850)...

Comment: Both of these factors multiplied with each other gives us positive- but why can't each of this factor be negative?(negative multiply negative gives us positive)

Comment: $a$ is positive. $\sqrt{b}$ is positive. When you add them, you get the positive number $ a + \sqrt{b}$, which is the second factor. So the first factor must also be positive.

Comment: Also, (+1) for interaction beyond just asking the question.

Comment: Oh, right. Awesome, thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose otherwise, i.e. that $a\leq \sqrt{b}$. Then $a^2=a\cdot a\leq \sqrt{b}\cdot a\leq \sqrt{b}\cdot\sqrt{b}=b$, so $a^2\leq b$, contradicting the fact that $a^2>\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! :-)

Comment: BTW, is $\sqrt{b}\cdot\sqrt{b}=b$ by definition or can it be proven?

Comment: @Anonymous By definition, according to any definition I've seen.