# How to prove that if $x>0$, $y>0$, and $x>y$, then $x^2>y^2$?

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that if $x>0$, $y>0$, and $x>y$, then $x^2>y^2$.

Here is **my attempt:**

Since $x>0$, $y>0$, and $x>y$,

may implies that $x+y>0$ and $x-y>0$.

Thus, $(x+y)(x-y)>0$.

Simplifying this

$x^2-y^2>0$

Therefore, $x^2>y^2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a > b$, is $a^2 > b^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/if-a-b-is-a2-b2)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the fact that $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

$x>y>0$ multiply on itself.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque. 
How can your remark be applied to what was written more then year ago? Please allow yourself to comment on recent incidents.